# Autohotkey custom Windows key popping up start menu

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, boot-camp

I have an `autohotkey` script like this:

```
RAlt::RWin ; right command to alt
RWin::RAlt ; right alt to command (windows key)
LWin::LAlt ; left command to alt
LAlt::LWin ; left alt to command (windows key)

#q:: Run "d:\Tools\mytool1.lnk"

#b:: Run "d:\Tools\mytool2.lnk"
```

I am on bootcamp so the first 4 lines I am remapping the `win` and `command` keys. I have issue with `#q::` and `#b::` mappings.

When I pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> I have my apps launched but at the same time when I am releasing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> the start menu pops up straight after.

Is there any way to stop the start menu appearing?

**UPDATE:**

I just comment the first 4 lines and I found that my #q and #b mappings not triggering start menu in such case. But I would prefer to keep the windows key mapping. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that helped me to avoid this on Windows 10: separate the hotkeys with the <kbd>Win</kbd> key defined in a file into several files, so that each file contains at most one of them. Example:

<sub>Before:</sub>

```
#E::Run, "some command";
#T::Run, "another command";
```

<sub>After: (two files)</sub>

```
#E::Run, "some command";
```

```
#T::Run, "another command";
```